# MySql select distinct with sum yields weird results

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select distinct tagName along with the sum of those tagNames, but seem to be getting only one result.

```
"gId"   "tagName"           "tagTotal"  "tagCountryCode"
"1"     "metallica"         "5"         "US"
"2"     "abba"              "5"         "US"
"3"     "metallica"         "1"         "US"
"4"     "abba"              "1"         "US"
"5"     "metallica"         "1"         "US"
"6"     "james-hetfield"    "1"         "US"
"7"     "abba"              "1"         "US"
"8"     "metallica"         "4"         "SE"
"9"     "abba"              "4"         "SE"
```

I'm using this query, but I'm failing. What am I doing wrong, and how do I do this right?

`select distinct tagName a, sum(tagTotal) b from tags where tagCountryCode = 'US' order by b desc limit 20;`

```
"a"         "b"
"metallica" "15"
```

I'm trying to get results like:

```
metallica      7
abba           7
james-hetfield 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a `group by`, not `distinct`:

```
select tagName, sum(tagTotal) as cnt
from tags
where tagCountryCode = 'US'
group by tagName
order by cnt desc
limit 20;
```

I changed the aliases to something more meaningful than `a` and `b`, but you can keep those if you like.